# sort ascending/descending vba excel not working

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I'm building a macro that sort ascending/descending a range of cells according to its values.
  The problem is that it is not working with the following data:

11_NR-10.pdf
   16_NR-10.pdf
   1_NR-10.pdf
   6_NR-10.pdf

When I try to sort, I get the following result:

1_NR-10.pdf
   11_NR-10.pdf
   16_NR-10.pdf
   6_NR-10.pdf

Does someone knows how to help me?

Code:

```
Dim xlSort As XlSortOrder
Dim LastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet

     LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     If (.Range("A3").Value > .Range("A" & CStr(LastRow))) Then
         xlSort = xlAscending
     Else
         xlSort = xlDescending
     End If

     .Range("A3:A" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=.Range("A3"), Order1:=xlSort, Header:=xlNo, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal


End With
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Comment: Well the sort is working correctly. The alphabetic sort is 1, 11, 2, 22 etc. not the realistic 1, 2, 11, 22. If you change the files names to 01, 11, 02, 22. The sort will be 01, 02, 11, 22.

Comment: If you place those four file names into four different column cells and ask Excel to sort them A-Z, that's exactly the sorting order you would get. Then, your code _is_ correct -- in the sense that it is replicating Excel's spreadsheet behaviour.

Comment: @PaulFrancis unfortunately I can't change the file names. It cannot contain any 0 on the left side.

Comment: @FaustoArinosBarbuto Unfortunately the file names needs to be in the same column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an auxiliar function just for this. Full untested code below :

```
Public Sub MySuperSort()
    Dim sortType31 As Integer, lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    sortType = ([A3] > Cells(lastRow, 1))
    Call MyOrder(Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)), 1, False)

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Private Sub MyOrder(ByVal tableRange As Range, ByVal columnIndex As Integer, ByVal ascending As Boolean, Optional ByVal header As Boolean = True)
    Dim orderBy As Integer, hasHeader As Integer
    orderBy = IIf(ascending, xlAscending, xlDescending)
    hasHeader = IIf(header, xlYes, xlNo)

    With tableRange.Parent
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add _
            Key:=Intersect(tableRange, tableRange.Columns(columnIndex)), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=orderBy, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .SetRange tableRange
            .header = hasHeader
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean like: MyOrder (.Range(.Cells(3,1).Cells(lastRow,1), 1, false) ?

Comment: Yes `Call MyOrder(.Range(.Cells(3,1).Cells(lastRow,1), 1, false)`

Comment: Sorry, it may look silly but where do I call MyOrder? Can I create a button and then simply call it passing its arguments?

Comment: It's returning syntax error on Call MyOrder(.Range(.Cells(3,1).Cells(lastRow,1), 1, false) . I'll try to fix it then I'll post it again if I still have problem

Comment: Forgot ")". Try it again.

Comment: register youself in Stackoverflow. :-)

Comment: I thought I was! :) Now it's giving me "Compiler error: Argument not optional"